# Problems getting VMware Server to work on Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, vmware-server

I'm trying to get VMware Server 2.0.2 (64-bit version) to work on my Ubuntu workstation.

However, the install script (`$ sudo ./vmware-install.pl`) runs into problems with the kernel modules:

```
[...]

What is the location of the directory of C header files that match your running
kernel? [/lib/modules/2.6.31-14-generic/build/include] 

Extracting the sources of the vmmon module.

Building the vmmon module.

Using 2.6.x kernel build system.
make: Entering directory `/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only'
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.31-14-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.31-14-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o
In file included from /tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:31:
/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/./include/compat_wait.h:78: error: conflicting types for ‘poll_initwait’
include/linux/poll.h:70: note: previous declaration of ‘poll_initwait’ was here
In file included from /tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/./include/vmware.h:38,
                 from /tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:99:
/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/./include/vm_basic_types.h:108:7: warning: "__FreeBSD__" is not defined
In file included from /tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/./include/vcpuset.h:103,
                 from /tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/./include/modulecall.h:37,
                 from /tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/./common/vmx86.h:33,
                 from /tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/linux/driver.h:29,
                 from /tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:101:
/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:329:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined
/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:333:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined
/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:401:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined
/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:407:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined
/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:460:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined
/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:506:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined
/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:551:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined
/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:595:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined
/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:640:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined
/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:684:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined
/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:729:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined
/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:945:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined
/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/./include/vm_atomic.h:947:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined

[...]

/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86.h:922:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined
In file included from /tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm.h:41,
                 from /tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:103:
/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86_64.h:56:7: warning: "_MSC_VER" is not defined
In file included from /tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:119:
/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/./common/hostif.h:53:7: warning: "WINNT_DDK" is not defined
/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c: In function ‘LinuxDriverSyncCallOnEachCPU’:
/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1423: error: too many arguments to function ‘smp_call_function’
/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c: In function ‘LinuxDriver_Ioctl’:
/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1987: error: ‘struct task_struct’ has no member named ‘euid’
/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1987: error: ‘struct task_struct’ has no member named ‘uid’
/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1988: error: ‘struct task_struct’ has no member named ‘fsuid’
/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1988: error: ‘struct task_struct’ has no member named ‘uid’
/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1989: error: ‘struct task_struct’ has no member named ‘egid’
/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1989: error: ‘struct task_struct’ has no member named ‘gid’
/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:2007: error: too many arguments to function ‘smp_call_function’
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.31-14-generic'
make: *** [vmmon.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/vmware-config4/vmmon-only'
Unable to build the vmmon module.

Execution aborted.
```

Am I missing some required packages? Any other ideas?

This is 64-bit Ubuntu 9.10 (Karmic Koala). `uname -a` returns `Linux hostname 2.6.31-14-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 16 14:05:01 UTC 2009 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

**Edit**: [Got VMware Server 2.0.2 working](https://superuser.com/questions/97276/problems-getting-vmware-server-2-0-to-work-on-ubuntu-9-10/97285#97285). However, if you have some tips on getting **VMware Server 1.0.x** to work with latest Ubuntu *easily* (without having to compile the whole kernel, for instance), please share those too! My first impression is that I don't like 2.0 at all, and would much rather use 1.0.x if only I got it working.

Comment: For what it's worth, I ended up dumping VMware Server altogether for now, after I found out that **VMware Player** does everything I currently need  (just run some existing Windows virtual machines). The UI and overall integration with Linux desktop is really smooth in Player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I got it working, with advice from 
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-vmware-server-2-0-x-in-ubuntu-9-10-karmic.html

1. Download this: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/images/vmware-server.2.0.1_x64-modules-2.6.30.4-fix.tgz and untar it. (This is for 2.0.1 but that does not seem to matter.)
2. Run `sudo sh vmware-server.2.0.1_x64-modules-2.6.30.4-fix.sh`

   NB: If you have VMware libs installed somewhere else than /usr/lib/ (e.g.  /usr/local/lib), you'll need to manually fix some paths in that script.
3. Then, as the script suggested, `sudo vmware-config.pl -d`

This finished up the configuration:

```
[...]

The configuration of VMware Server 2.0.2 build-203138 for Linux for this 
running kernel completed successfully.
```

Running `vmware` now launches the web UI at https://localhost:8333/ui/.

(Now, VMware 2.0 feels totally strange, and I don't really know how to access/use the web interface, but that's another story... In fact, if anyone knows of an *easy* way of getting VMware Server 1.0.10 to work with the latest Ubuntu, I'd like to know too!)

### Update

I've given up using VMware Server altogether as it's [no longer supported](http://radu.cotescu.com/vmware-server-kernel-2-6-38/) and it's become increasingly difficult to get it working on modern Ubuntu versions. If you need to create & run Windows virtual machines, check out e.g. [**this question on Ask Ubuntu**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43365/creating-running-windows-virtual-machines) for alternative ways.

Comment: Useful thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1313055. Seems like to use 1.0.x on latest Ubuntu you'd need to use an older kernel or then compile the whole kernel yourself. :-/